# visualization of posterior distribution for a matrix?

Tags: r, bayesian, data-visualization, random-variable, posterior

Via Bayesian analysis, I generate the posterior samples for a 2D matrix, representing a correlation matrix for instance. Is there any way or tool to visualize these two dimensional random samples?

Answer (score 1):

A two-dimensional correlation matrix could be visualized via an ellipse in the plane, see for instance

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556180/how-can-i-plot-a-correlation-matrix-as-a-set-of-ellipses-similar-to-the-r-open
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453336/plot-correlation-matrix-into-a-graph

But that is one correlation matrix, and you ask for a sample. You could try overplotting them (maybe using transparency), or clustering them and plotting representatives.